# SELECT after INNER JOIN fails

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am pretty new to SQL and I encountered something that is kind of strange in my opinion:

I have the following query:

```
SELECT id 
FROM Worker
INNER JOIN Computer ON Worker.Id = Computer.Id
```

Pretty simple stuff. This query will fail though and I think that this query failing is counterintuitively.

The query will fail because I'll have 2 columns called `id`. I could make the query work by writing:

```
SELECT Worker.id 
FROM Worker
INNER JOIN Computer ON Worker.Id = Computer.Id
```

My question is:

Why does my query require me to state what table I want the id from because

1. It doesn't matter from which table I get it
2. I pretty much stated that I want it from the 'worker' table by saying `SELECT Worker.id FROM Worker`

and is there a better way to define what table I want the id from besides writing `SELECT Worker.id FROM Worker`  because I feel as if I repeated myself in a way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is dependent on how each database provider handles their own query syntax, but here are my thoughts:

> 1) It doesn't matter from which table I get it

It might not matter in your example, but what about instances when the data types do not match (`int/smallint`, `date/datetime`, `int/string`)? Or if you are using a `left/right join` rather than an `inner join`? In these cases, the database provider would have to make a choice.

---

> 2) I pretty much stated that I want it from the 'worker' table by
>   saying SELECT Worker.id FROM

Yes you could use the order of the tables to resolve the ambiguity. Once again this is a decision the database provider could make.

---

> is there a better way to define what table I want the id from besides
>   writing SELECT Worker.id FROM Worker because I feel as if I repeated
>   myself in a way

I try to avoid using `inner joins` for filtering. Instead I would write the query like this:

```
SELECT id FROM Worker where id in (select id FROM Computer)
```

or

```
SELECT id FROM Worker as w where exists (select 1 from Computer as c where c.id = w.id)
```

*(these may not return the same results as your query, because the `inner join` could cause duplicates)*

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can you tell my why you avoid inner joins?

Comment: @ViktorG - I only avoid them when they are used for filtering (you are not selecting any columns from the join table or using it in a subsequent join). I feel it makes the query more readable and you avoid having to add `distinct` to your queries

Answer (score 1):

> This query will fail though and I think that this query failing is counterintuitive.

I think it's pretty clear why the query would fail. At least I haven't seen a DB implementation where it wouldn't fail (MySQL will fail with the message "column id is ambiguous", PostgreSQL will fail with the message "ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous" and MS-SQL will state something very similar), but there may exist implementations where it wouldn't fail.

> Why does my query require me to state what table I want the id from.

Because the column `id` is present in two tables.

> 1) It doesn't matter from which table I get it

That's what you say, but how is the database supposed to know? Imagine you have timestamps in two tables (let's call them `table_A` and `table_B`) indicating when a record was inserted into the table. Now you tell the DB: "Hey, join `table_A` and `table_B`, oh and please give me the timestamps!"

How is the DB supposed to know which timestamps you mean?

> 2) I pretty much stated that I want it from the 'worker' table by saying SELECT id FROM Worker

You said you want data from *Worker*, joined with data from *Computer*! You will get one single table by joining two tables together. You have to explicitly state where each row comes from, if there are row names that occur in more than one table. Going back to the previous example, if `table_A` has a row called *file_size* and `table_B` does not, then it is enough to say

```
SELECT file_size
FROM table_A
    JOIN table_B on table_A.id = table_B.id
```

because there only is one column with that name.

> and is there a better way to define what table I want the id from besides writing SELECT Worker.id FROM Worker because I feel as if I repeated myself in a way

Another possiblitly -apart from the suggestions Aducci made- would be to make use of aliases, like this:

```
SELECT w.id
FROM Worker AS w
    INNER JOIN Computer AS c ON w.Id = c.Id
```

that way you don't have to type out the whole table names every time.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server specifically, please observe this query.

```
DECLARE @var1 date ='01/01/2017'
DECLARE @Var2 varchar(20)='01/01/2017'

if (@var1=@Var2)
BEGIN
    select 'match'
END
```

The result is it says it matches because of implicit data casting. How would the SQL engine know which value to provide in an instance like this? Personally, I like that it requires the alias in that particular product.